# Need help on managing build flavours and build types in complex scenario

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've to launch an application in 4 different countries(assume A, B, C and D as four different countries). Code base is same for all countries but there are minor changes in UI screens for each country.
For each country specific there are 3 different environments. For e.g. dev, prod and qa. Each environment points to different urls for each country.
So basically 4 (countries) x 3 (environments) = 12 urls
For example

1. Country A, prod --> url-1
2. Country A, qa   --> url-2
3. Country B, prod --> url-3

Same for other countries and environments.

---

### Current implementation

productFlavors {

```
    Aprod {
       // uri for prod, for country A
    }

    Aqa {
       // uri for qa, for country A
    }

    Adev {
       // uri for dev, for country A
    }

    Bprod {
       // uri for prod, for country B
    }

    Bqa {
       // uri for qa, for country B
    }

    ..... // for other countries and environments
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // lines removed
    }
    debug {
       // lines removed
    }
```

Dis-advantage :

1. If a image resource is different for country A and B then in order to maintain this, I'll have to create 3 different folders like Aprod, Aqa etc and place same image to all these folders and same for country B and it's environments.

---

### Other approach

I can maintain A, B, C and D as flavours. I'll create prod, qa and dev as build types but then I'll change the definition of build types If I do that.
As per my research flavours indicate different builds which are functionally different and build types are basically same app but debug and release version. So that means I can not have prod, qa as build type.

What is the approach recommended in cases like this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
I've resolved the issue with the help of dimension concept. Please see the answer below.

    flavorDimensions "country", "environment"

    productFlavors {

        A {
            dimension "country"
        }

        B {
            dimension "country"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        qa {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

This will create 2 x 2 x 2 = 8 build types.
AProdRelease
AProdDebug
AQaRelease
AQaDebug
Same for B country.

In order to inject values (resValue and buildConfigField) to each build type I've written small function.

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      // inject values
}

if things are not clear then message me, I'll update it with more details.
```